# Height UIImage asynchronously in UITableview with autolayout

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am showing an image in a UITableView, the image will have different sizes and it is downloaded via JSON, with the following code the image is shown correctly scaled but there are some large spaces up and down (green color). How could I eliminate those spaces?

The image has the constraints top, bottom, left and right to 0 to be able to use the autolayout

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    struct JsonSosTalleres : Codable {
        let titulo : String
        let image : String
    }

    private var datosOfertas = [JsonSosTalleres]()

    class ImageLoader {

        var cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

        class var sharedInstance : ImageLoader {
            struct Static {
                static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
            }
            return Static.instance
        }

        func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ image: UIImage?, _ url: String) -> ()) {
            let data: NSData? = self.cache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? NSData

            if let imageData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(image, urlString)
                }
                return
            }

            let downloadTask: URLSessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL.init(string: urlString)!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if data != nil {
                        let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                        self.cache.setObject(data! as AnyObject, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completionHandler(image, urlString)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil, urlString)
                }
            }
            downloadTask.resume()
        }
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var tabla: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJson()


        tabla.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0

        tabla.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        tabla.tableFooterView = UIView()

    }








    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datosOfertas.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tabla.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ofertacell") as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


        let fimage = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].image
        ImageLoader.sharedInstance.imageForUrl(urlString: fimage, completionHandler: { (image, url) in
            if image != nil {


               tableView.beginUpdates()

                cell.imagen.image = image

                tableView.endUpdates()


            }
        })



        return cell
    }




    // download  json
    let url = URL(string: "http://sostalleres.com/test.json")

    func downloadJson() {
        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("something is wrong")
                return
            }
            print("downloaded")
            do
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.datosOfertas = [try decoder.decode(JsonSosTalleres.self, from: data)]

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            self.tabla.reloadData()

                }

            } catch {
                print("something wrong after downloaded")
            }
            }.resume()
    }





}
```

and in TableViewCell.swift :

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagen: UIImageView!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctjCs.png)

I would appreciate if you can guide me in any solution.

Comment: If the imageView in your cell has *"constraints top, bottom, left and right to 0"*, and you are using it to determine the height of the cell (`tabla.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`), it also needs height and width constraints. What do you have those set to?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
If I put the height to the image it shows me like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoNjV.png  (As I was reviewing so that the height is dynamic, it should not have height or width)

Comment: Well, you will *have* to set the height in some fashion. Commonly, when your code has downloaded the image, you get the width / height of the downloaded image and adjust the frame of your image view as desired (in the case of auto-layout, you would keep an `@IBOutlet` reference to a width or height constraint(or both)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate the new height and width and with them apply the scale and use `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, with the following code you should work without problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tabla.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ofertacell") as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


        let fimage = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].image
        ImageLoader.sharedInstance.imageForUrl(urlString: encoded!, completionHandler: { (image, url) in
            if image != nil {


                let newWidth = self.self.imagenDetalle.frame.width
                let scale = newWidth/(image?.size.width)!
                let newHeight = (image?.size.height)! * scale



                        tableView.beginUpdates()

                        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
                        image?.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
                        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        cell.imagen.image = newImage

                        tableView.endUpdates()


            }
        })



        return cell
    }
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up height and width constraints and creating corresponding outlets:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet private weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

You can create an image property on that same cell which uses the size to set the image view size and image:

```
internal var image: UIImage? {
    willSet {
        imageView.image = newValue
        guard let image = newValue else { return }
        heightConstraint.constant = image.size.height
        widthConstraint.constant = image.size.width
    }
}
```

This (likely incorrectly) assumes each image is the perfect size. If this is not the case you will need to do some scaling yourself.